# Problem with spacy.load("en_core_web_md") in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, spacy

I'm struggling with installation of package en_core_web_md from spaCy library. After executing

```
spacy.load("en_core_web_md")
```

I get this error: OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_md'. It doesn't seem to be a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.

I used this command in the terminal:

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_md
```

And terminal returned this output:

[image]

I installed it manually as well, using .whl file and this command:

[image]

Still after executing this line of code:

```
print(spacy.util.get_installed_models())
```

I recive empty brackets [], so no wonder when I execute my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import spacy


def lemmatize_text(text):
    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")
    doc = nlp(text)
    return " ".join([token.lemma_ for token in doc])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(spacy.util.get_installed_models())

    database = pd.read_csv('database.csv')

    database['Lyric'] = database['Lyric'].apply(lemmatize_text)

    database.to_csv('database.csv', index=False)
```

I get this output in console

[image]

OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_md'. It doesn't seem to be a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.

What is wrong with my installation? I'm using PyCharm 2023.1, Python 3.11.3 and Windows 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you download `en_core_web_md` you need to `Restart Runtime` or `Ctrl+M` from the menu bar.